# Problems with route in Laravel

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

After clicking in view,

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'route' => ['city', $city->id]]) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Check', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

system finds this route:

```
Route::get('city/{id}', 'CityController@show')->name('city');
```

which makes URL in web browser look like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/game/public/city/5?
```

problem is however, that when I click on another link for example:

```
<li><a href="home">Reports</a> </li>
```

I get URL in following format:

```
http://localhost:8888/game/public/city/home
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:8888/game/public/home
```

Which is wrong since it doesn't work. How do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use relative URLs. You can use the **url** helper to generate a fully qualified url.

```
<a href="{{ url('home') }}">Home</a>
```

Reference:

[Laravel Docs - Helpers - url method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url)